# For each loop not executing more than once in php

Tags: php, loops

I have two fields in form one is name and other is email like this.

```
<td class="left"><input style="  width: 30%; text-align: center;" type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $geo_zone['name']; ?>" /></td>
<td class="left"><input style="  width: 30%; text-align: center;" type="email" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $geo_zone['email']; ?>" /></td>
```

There name are array types so that i can store multiple values in them on run time because my form is generated on run time and may have multiple names and emails depending on database result.

In my controller iam just fetching these values in print_r() iam getting writes results. but when i execute my for each loop it just runs one time and inserts last row in database.

```
$name= $this->request->post['name'];

$email= $this->request->post['email'];

foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {

$this->data['geo_zone_id']=$this->model_module_shipping_pools->Get_geo_zone_id($n);

$geo_zone_id=$this->data['geo_zone_id'];
$geo_zone_id=$geo_zone_id[0]['geo_zone_id'];

$this->model_module_shipping_pools->drop_data();
$mail=$email[$key];
$this->model_module_shipping_pools->insertData($geo_zone_id,$mail);
```

I have no idea why its just running one time. I am working in opencart.

Comment: it's running one time because there is only one text input in the HTML array `name[]`, that's the same exactly when you create an array in PHP and fill it with one element

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple input tag with the same array name to have an array value!

For example (I don't know how you generate the original html) you may have:

```
<td class="left"><input style="  width: 30%; text-align: center;" type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $geo_zone['name'][0]; ?>" /></td>
<td class="left"><input style="  width: 30%; text-align: center;" type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $geo_zone['name'][1]; ?>" /></td>
...
```

See an example on how to use array [here](http://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays)